# .raw file format C++

Tags: c++, file, file-io, paraview

I want to know is it possible to generate .raw file format using C++. If yes then which class deals with it? If possible kindly put down a sample code.

I have data of the format `(X Y Z) <Number>` which represents the number of particles between `(X Y Z)` and `(X+1 Y+1 Z+1)`. I need to represent this data graphically using [ParaView](http://paraview.org) and hence need my data in binary format. So would like to know is it possible to directly generate .raw file format?

Comment: `.raw` files are usually image files. "Raw format" used by [ParaView](http://paraview.org/) is a completely different thing, so you might want to emphasize this in your question. Do you have exact specifications of this format? [This page](http://paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView:FAQ) only mentions: *ParaView supports reading raw uniform rectilinear data from a file. The default file extension is .raw. The user specifies the dimensions and data type, and the reader computes the header size*, which is a bit vague (at least for me).

Comment: This was the biggest problem. The wikipage does not mention clearly for a novice like me.
Anyways eventually we have to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, to write binary data to a file in C++, you will want to use an `ofstream`:

```
#include <fstream.h>
...

{
   MyData myData = GetData();
   ofstream binaryFile ("file.raw", ios::out | ios::binary);
   binaryFile.write ((char*)&myData, sizeof (MyData));
   binaryFile.close();
}
```

It is up to you to determine the actual format (like the `Data` structure in the example above) that this application uses, and then write it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

There are many definitions of raw image files, it very much depends on the context. The oldest and simplest definition is a file with no header and with pixel values packed in binary without any compression. This is trivial to implement, just write each pixel as 3 `unsigned char` values for red, green, and blue, from left to right and top to bottom.

Comment: @Groo, that just proves my point that `.raw` is completely dependent on the context.