# Send audio data from usermode to Sysvad (virtual audio driver) use IOCTL

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, ioctl

In my application(usermode), i receive audio data and save it use function:

```
VOID CSoundRecDlg::ProcessHeader(WAVEHDR * pHdr)
{
    MMRESULT mRes=0;
    TRACE("%d",pHdr->dwUser);
    if(WHDR_DONE==(WHDR_DONE &pHdr->dwFlags))
    {
        mmioWrite(m_hOPFile,pHdr->lpData,pHdr->dwBytesRecorded);
        mRes=waveInAddBuffer(m_hWaveIn,pHdr,sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        if(mRes!=0)
            StoreError(mRes,TRUE,"File: %s ,Line Number:%d",__FILE__,__LINE__);
    }
}
```

pHdr Pointer points to the audio data(byte[11025])
How to I can get this data in sysvad using IOCTL. Thanks for help.

Comment: Why IOCTL? You're suppose to be able to use standard audio API to talk to this/any audio driver, ie: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/rendering-a-stream

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks you for comment. Sorry,My english is bad.I had no knowledge of this and tried to learn, I followed what I found. It was a [guide](https://community.osr.com/discussion/292250/help-with-design-decision-using-sysvad-virtual-driver-as-base) almost like what I intended to do. Here my audio from microphone to skype and sysvad as an intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have an audio buffer than you want to send for output in sysvad. For this case scenario you would have to write the butter in using "writebytes"
please look at this example for more in depth details.

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/audio/sysvad/EndpointsCommon/minwavertstream.cpp

**UPDATE**

in answer to your comment:

Circular buffer is not a must it really depends from the implementation you want to do, the main point is to get the buffer in memory, writing it is simply like this

```
 adapterObject->WriteEtwEvent(eMINIPORT_LAST_BUFFER_RENDERED,
                                    m_ullLinearPosition + ByteDisplacement, // Current linear buffer position  
                                    m_ulCurrentWritePosition, // The very last WaveRtBufferWritePosition that the driver received
                                    0,
                                    0);
```

ideally you would use separation of concerns with the logic for reading and writing independent from each other, with the buffer object just passed between them

Comment: I know I have to use a separate circular buffer to do this but I don't know where to declare it or how to create it. I just found a tutorial[https://community.osr.com/discussion/292250/help-with-design-decision-using-sysvad-virtual-driver-as-base] but don't understand

Comment: Can you show me some sample projects that do this job (send audio data from usermode to sysvad). I still don't understand this and how to implement it. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Hello LemonCool! I have found a piece of [code](https://ibb.co/84Wv554) that stores data but I wonder if it is a circular buffer. Can you explain to me about PNOISE_DATA_STRUCTURE?. Perhaps [this](https://ibb.co/02CLtWT) is how they pull the data out.Can you explain me what is m_pExtensionData? Please help me. Thanks you.